# Angular - custom validator does not use latest value of component variable

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I have the following form group that gets created in  `ngOnInit`:

```
  private setScreeningStatusForm(screeningStatusData: ClientScreeningStatusModel | undefined): void {
    this.screeningStatusForm = new FormGroup({
      field_screening_status_select: new FormControl(screeningStatusData?.status, [Validators.required, this.screeningStatusValidator().bind(this)]),
      field_screening_status_comment: new FormControl(screeningStatusData?.userComment)
    });
  }
```

I have the following validator that ensures the user cannot save the same option (where `this.screeningStatus` is the currently saved option and gets updated when saving):

```
  private screeningStatusValidator(): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
      return this.screeningStatus?.status === control.value ? { 'invalidStatusSelection': true } : null;
    };
  }
```

I'm running into an issue whereby when validating, the validator uses the original value of `this.screeningStatus` rather than the latest value. As you can see in the code, I've tried binding `this` to the validator to get the latest value but no dice.

Do I have to recreate the form group or remove/re-add the validator everytime `this.screeningStatus` changes? I have a working solution where I am doing this in the `set` of the `this.screeningStatus`:

```
  public set screeningStatus(value: ClientScreeningStatusModel | undefined) {
    this._screeningStatus = value;
    this.setScreeningStatusForm(value);
  }
```

and this works without needing to bind, however it is clunky and I'd like the bind to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It would be a lot easier to help with a StackBlitz example.

Comment: You cannot `bind` an arrow function

Comment: @Shlang what should my validator function look like in that case for bind to work? Something like `private screeningStatusValidator(control: AbstractControl) {
    return this.screeningStatus?.status === control.value ? { 'invalidStatusSelection': true } : null;
  }` works  with `this.screeningStatusValidator.bind(this)` - which I guess makes sense but haven't ever used a validator function like this - does this seem like the correct approach?

Comment: You can return `function` from the validator factory, so `bind` would work, and you can pass a getter function as a validator factory argument. It has nothing to do with angular or validators, it is a core JS knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to make sure the next status is not the same as the one alreadySet.

If you want the data to be updated each type there is a change, you could use a BahaviourSuject for that.

```
 this._screeningStatus = new BehaviorSubject(this.cleaningStatus); // set the initalValue of the status
```

Then, you should create only once the form.

Create your form in the ngOnInit function with the screeningStatus validator and the behaviour subject as a parameter;

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.screeningStatusForm = new FormGroup({
      field_screening_status_select: new FormControl(undefined, [Validators.required, this.screeningStatusValidator(this._screeningStatus)]),
      field_screening_status_comment: new FormControl()
    });
}
```

And then, you should modify your setter to set the values to the form

```
public set screeningStatus(value: ClientScreeningStatusModel | undefined) {
   this.screeningStatusForm.controls.field_screening_status_select.setValue(value?.status);
   this.screeningStatusForm.controls.field_screening_status_comment.setValue(value?.userComment;

  // This needs to be after, to be sure not to test the same value
  this._screeningStatus.next(value);
}
```

And adapt the validator as such

```
private screeningStatusValidator(screeningStatus: BehaviorSubject<ClientScreeningStatusModel>): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
      return screeningStatus.value.status === control.value ? { 'invalidStatusSelection': true } : null;
    };
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. I think this approach makes sense. In the nsetScreeningStatus, how should this look if the screeningStatusForm is in another component? I'd want to do .next() before setting the control values I assume?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve, but the BehaviorSubject is there to provide an initialValue, therefore there is no need to do the .next() before setting the control values. Perhaps you could edit your question and add both component so we can help in a better way.